# Cookie max age in Java

Tags: java, cookies

What is the difference between this:

```
cookie.setMaxAge(0);
```

and this

```
cookie.setMaxAge(-1);
```

Does first make it removed?

Comment: it is probably explained in the corresponding documentation.

Comment: Do you mean javax.servlet.http.Cookie? Then just read the documentation: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/http/Cookie.html#setMaxAge(int)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> A negative value means that the cookie is not stored persistently and
>   will be deleted when the Web browser exits. A zero value causes the
>   cookie to be deleted.

http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/Cookie.html#setMaxAge%28int%29

Answer (score 8):

Assuming we are talking about `javax.servlet.http.Cookie`

This is what [Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/Cookie.html#setMaxAge%28int%29) says

**setMaxAge**
**public void setMaxAge(int expiry)**

> Sets the maximum age in seconds for this Cookie.
>
> > A positive value
> >     indicates that the cookie will expire after that many seconds have
> >     passed. Note that the value is the maximum age when the cookie will
> >     expire, not the cookie's current age.
>
> A negative value means that the cookie is not stored persistently and
>   will be deleted when the Web browser exits.
>
> > A zero value causes the
> >     cookie to be deleted.

Answer (score 2):

From [RFC 6265](http://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/rfc6265/?include_text=1):

> If delta-seconds is less than or equal to zero (0), let expiry-time
>      be the earliest representable date and time.  Otherwise, let the
>      expiry-time be the current date and time plus delta-seconds seconds.

Therefore, both have the cookie expire as soon as possible *on a compliant user-agent*.

However, in practice, negative values imply session cookies.

Answer (score 2):

cookie.setMaxAge( 0 ) will delete the cookie right away.

cookie.setMaxAge( -1 ) will preserve the cookie for a while and delete the cookie when the browser exits.

For relevant information refer the [API Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.3/api/javax/servlet/http/Cookie.html#setMaxAge%28int%29).